# Confusion between Lie Algebra representation and adjoint representation

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

For the Lie group $SU(2)$ which can be represented as a subset of $GL(\mathbb{C}^2)$, we know that the Lie Algebra $su(2)$ can be represented as a subset of $End(\mathbb{C}^2)$.

I'm confused by what this last bit is referring to, and the difference between the Lie Algebra representation and the adjoint representation.

I've heard that the Lie Algebra of $SU(2)$, $su(2)=span(\sigma_i)$ is the 3D span of the 3 2x2 Pauli matrices. Is the above saying that *this* is the subset of $End(\mathbb{C}^2)$?

Alternatively the adjoint representation of SU(2) can be represented by 3x3 matrices. Is *this* what it means by the subset of $End(\mathbb{C}^2)$? (I would assume not?)

I'm also slightly confused of what the point of the adjoint representation is since the Pauli matrices already represent the Lie Bracket correctly with their matrix commutator, so what is the point of having a new 3x3 matrix system of showing the same thing?

Comment: There is also an "adjoint representation" for Lie algebras, given by $x\mapsto {\rm ad}(x)$, where ${\rm ad}(x)=[x,y]$. So $\rho={\rm ad}\colon L \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(L)\cong \mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)$ is a morphism of Lie algebras, with $\dim (L)=n$. In your case, $n=3$, $L\cong \mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Comment: If $G$ is a Lie group and $H\subset G$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, then there is a natural embedding $Lie(H)\subset Lie(G)$. In your case $Lie(GL_2)=End(\mathbb{C}^2)$, which is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices. Basically, the span of $2\times 2$ of Pauli matrices is the one that is referred.

Answer (score 1):

It is the first case. The span of $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices is the one that is being referred to by $End( \mathbb{C^2})$